# Orchard Changing Site Culture doesn't Change Menu

Tags: c#, navigation, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

In my Orchard Project I added the [Datwendo Localization Module](https://bitbucket.org/csurieux/datwendo.localization). I have the Culture `de` and `en`. When I change the cultre on the current Site, the translation is also changing.

My problem is that menu is not chaning. So when I changed my culture to `en`, Menu is still showing the `de` links.

I created the page, and checked show on Menu. Then I created the translation and also checked show on menu.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try [RM.Localization](https://rmlocalization.codeplex.com/documentation). I am feeling good with this module. I guess you will need it.
I didn't try Datwendo Localization Module, because I have something wrong with the 
installation.